# ubuntu OS : Why my battery is completely drained of in just 2 hours in suspend mode

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system

Why my battery is completely drained of in just 2 hours in suspend mode

i tried by running many terminal commands but it doesn't fix,when i left my system in suspend mode for sometime it becomes really hot and the battery is drained of completely,the pc gets discharged